# Can jsp_service() method be overridden?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I know that the `jsp_service()` method cannot be overridden, but one of my friends said that we could use scriptlets in JSP to override the method and could do whatever we need in that method.

Can anyone explain it's true?

Comment: That's where the codes within scriptlets are executed. It's not the same as overriding a method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not Its not true.

Take a sample JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you check generated Servlet for this JSP. You will find `_jspService` method containing HTML code as `out.write`

Why ?

Since what ever we wrote code in the JSP will be placed in `_jspService()` of generated servlet class(from JSP) .means `_jspService()` is already imlimented by us.So if we attempted to override `_jspService()` it will give a compilation error regarding the method `_jspService()` is already defined.

Read More [why jspService() cannot be overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288514/why-jspservice-cannot-be-overridden)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever we write inside the scriplet gets converted into `jsp_service()` method into the generated Servlet. So, to override this method, you can simply write the code in scriplet. But, you can not manually override this method. It will result in compilation failure.